# Incorrect results from three table join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have these three tables in my database:

```
tblCustomer (id,name,address)
tblLoan (id,customerId,LoanAmount,date)
tblPayment (id,customerId,ReceivedAmount,date)
```

I want to find the total loanAmount for a customer and how much they have paid.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT c.fname, SUM(l.amount), SUM(p.amount)
FROM tblCustomer c
JOIN tblLoan l ON (l.customerId = c.id)
JOIN tblPayment p ON (p.customerId = c.id)
WHERE c.id = 3;
```

It returns results but they are incorrect.

Comment: do you mean 'total ReceivedAmount' and 'total LoanAmount' or you mean per each loan?

Comment: OP, are you still working on this one?

Answer (score 1):

First, as others have mentioned, your syntax is likely incorrect because you do not have matching column names, but you said you had incorrect results, so I would assume that's not your problem as you were able to run your query..

The problem that I think you are most likely having is that by joining the two tables together like that, rows appear twice for each customer. Am I correct in assuming that your 'incorrect' results are double what you would expect? Let me illustrate for those who don't understand. Consider this data set, with shortened column values:

tblCustomer:

```
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Adam |
|  2 | John |
|  3 | Jane |
```

tblLoan, and for simplicity we'll say the payment table looks the same:

```
| customerID | loanAmount |
+------------+------------+
|     1      |     100    |
|     2      |     200    |
|     3      |     300    |
|     3      |     300    |
|     2      |     200    |
```

If I perform the following query (without summing values, just getting the values I want:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, l.loanAmount, p.receivedAmount
FROM tblCustomer c
JOIN tblLoan l ON l.customerid = c.id
JOIN tblPayment p ON p.customerid = c.id
WHERE c.id = 3;
```

It returns this result set:

```
| id | name | loanAmount | receivedAmount |
+----+------+------------+----------------+
| 3  | Jane |    100     |       100      |
| 3  | Jane |    100     |       300      |
| 3  | Jane |    300     |       100      |
| 3  | Jane |    300     |       300      |
```

So notice that because we're joining two tables based on a relationship to a third table, were actually creating a cartesian product which is causing the problem. So, what I recommend you do is use subqueries for these two tables. One subquery will pull the loan values, one the payment values, and you can join those together on the id value.

It will look like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.totalLoan, w.totalReceived
FROM(SELECT c.id, SUM(l.loanAmount) AS totalLoan
    FROM tblCustomer c
    JOIN tblLoan l ON l.customerid = c.id
    WHERE c.id = 3) t
JOIN(SELECT c.id, SUM(p.receivedAmount) AS totalReceived
    FROM tblCustomer c
    JOIN tblPayment p ON p.customerid = c.id
    WHERE c.id = 3) w
ON t.id = w.id;
```

And this should give you the values you want. Here is what I tested on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47e372/2).

Answer (score -1):

FYI, **YOUR COLUMN NAMES ARE WRONG!!!**

1. There is no such column named `fname` in table `tblCustomer`
2. There is no such column named `amount` in table `tblLoan`
3. There is no such column named `amount` in table `tblPayment`

You won't get the right result if you don't have the appropriate column names. Even when using aliases, your column name should be **EXACTLY THE SAME** as in your database table. That's because, you are aliasing **TABLES** in `JOIN` queries, not **COLUMNS**.

So, re-write your query in the following way:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(l.LoanAmount), SUM(p.ReceivedAmount)
FROM tblCustomer c
JOIN tblLoan l ON l.customerId = c.id
JOIN tblPayment p ON p.customerId = c.id
WHERE c.id = 3
```

Note that there's no need to get brackets around the `ON` clause in `JOIN`.

Comment: I feel like the capital letters and bolding are kind of harsh here. **YOUR COLUMN NAMES ARE WRONG!!!** Sounds like you're shoving it in OP's face that they've made a mistake.

Comment: Further, I highly doubt the syntax is the problem. If it was, OP wouldn't get any results. But they're getting *incorrect* results, so I would make the assumption they could at least run and execute their query.

Comment: He's getting incorrect results, but didn't show us the results. Besides, I really don't get it - How's he supposed to get results when using wrong column names? And yeah, sorry, it does seem quite harsh to capitalize and bold those phrases. Sorry for that.